# Can I copy a Moq Mock implementation?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I've been using Moq and loving it, but I've come across a problem mocking some legacy code (before I try to refactor it away)

What I really want to do is have two separate mocks, with only slightly different implementation, such as the sample below.

```
        Mock<IFoo> fooMock = new Mock<IFoo>();
        fooMock.SetupGet(f => f.bar).Returns(7);
        fooMock.SetupGet(f => f.bar2).Returns(3);
        Mock<IFoo> fooMockClone = new Mock<IFoo>(fooMock.Behavior);
        fooMockClone.SetupGet(f => f.bar).Returns(9);

        Debug.Assert(7 == fooMock.Object.bar);
        Debug.Assert(9 == fooMockClone.Object.bar);
        Debug.Assert(3 == fooMockClone.Object.bar2);
        Debug.Assert(3 == fooMock.Object.bar2);
```

This is a simple example but the real code is an object with dozens of methods and I want slightly different implementation for two versions.

Thanks

Comment: Your question seems confusing -- did you have a copy-paste "whoopsie" with the second fooMock setup and the second assertion?

Comment: You're absolutely right. I did. Fixed. Thanks :)

Comment: Wait, do you just want one mock object whose value changes each time you access it or something?

Answer (score 1):

I wonder in this case then if you're looking for Behavior tests.  Here's a sample in Machine.Fakes with the Moq sublayer ... it allows for the nesting it seems like you're wanting, while still maintaining logical separation of the tests.  Requires NuGet packages: Machine.Fakes.Moq, Machine.Specifications.Should

```
class IFoo_test_context : WithSubject<IFoo>
{
    Establish context = () => Subject.bar2 = 3;
}

class When_fooing_with_seven : IFoo_test_context
{
    Establish context = () => Subject.bar = 7;

    It bar_should_be_seven =()=> Subject.bar.ShouldEqual(7);
    It bar2_should_be_three =()=> Subject.bar.ShouldEqual(3);
}

class When_fooing_with_nine : IFoo_test_context
{
    Establish context = () => Subject.bar = 9;

    It bar_should_be_nine = () => Subject.bar.ShouldEqual(9);
    It bar2_should_be_three = () => Subject.bar.ShouldEqual(3);
}
```

Again the example is somewhat silly because it's testing the mocking behavior, but it's hard to see what you're ultimately trying to accomplish.  There is no copy constructor in the way you want with Mock as far as I can tell.

Comment: I copied your example, with my modification, and it worked in Moq 4.2.1409.1722 from NuGet as of 2014-09-18.

Comment: I believe that fooMock.Behaviour just returns if the mock was created with MockBehaviour.Strict, Loose or Default (I updated my terrible example to show a bit clearer what I actually wanted. Sorry...)

Comment: I've updated my answer based on your edits to the original question.

Comment: @insta I think your original (unedited) response addressed the original (and edited) question exactly...

Answer (score 0):

You don't mock implementation details, you mock values so that you can get to a point in your code that you need to test. There's no point in writing a test that tests whether a mocked dependency outputs a value, then you're just testing moq.

Ex:

```
public class Stuff {
    IFoo _foo;
    IBar _bar;
    public Stuff(IFoo foo, IBar bar){
        _foo = foo;
        _bar = bar;
    }
    public void DoStuff() {
        if(_foo.HasFooage) {
            _bar.Bar = 4;
        }
    }
}
```

Then your test would:

```
...
public void test_bar_does_bar() {
    var foo = new Mock<IFoo>();
    foo.Setup(f => f.HasFooage).Returns(true);
    var bar = new Mock<IBar>();
    var stuff = new Stuff(foo.Object, bar.Object);

    stuff.DoStuff();

    Assert.That(bar.Bar, Is.EqualTo(4));
}
```

Comment: I believe you missed the point. OP just tried to distill the problem down to the point where a short answer could be given.

Comment: Ask yourself this: What's the point of doing a debug.assert on whether or not your mock object has the value you specifically set it up to have in it... ?

Comment: I want to pass the object to a method I am testing and test that the value it has been set to is as expected. Using SetProperty might have made this a little clearer that it would be set later. I'm discovering that my example was terrible in many ways.

Comment: Maybe you want to post the actual code you're trying to test?

Comment: @MikeCreeda I made an edit. Is that closer to what you're looking for?

Comment: @CBauer I agree that this example has the flaws you mention, but it's trivial to look past them and see the underlying theme of the question (for example, OP could have changed `.Returns(7)` to `.Returns(() => { return fooMockClone.SomeFunction(); })` for a more valid real-world scenario, but I don't see how it adds to the "answer-ability" of the question).